# typescript function variable with generics

Tags: generics, typescript

How can I pass the parameter to a variable that saves a function —

```
export const filter = Curry(_filter) as ICurryFunction<T>
```

I get the error — `Cannot find name T`

The `filter` constant stores a function.

**Curry.ts**

```
function Curry<T, R> (f: ICurryFunction<T>): ICurryFunction<T> {
  return function curried (...t: any[]): T | ICurryFunction<T> {
    if (t.length === 0) return curried
    if (t.length >= f.length) return f(...t)
    return curried.bind(this, ...t)
  }
}
```

**ICurryFunction.ts**

```
interface ICurryFunction<T> {
  (...k: any[]): T | ICurryFunction<T>
}
```

**Complete Code** 
https://github.com/tusharmath/observable-air/blob/master/src/main.ts#L24

Comment: Show the code of `Curry` and `ICurryFunction<T>`

Comment: @haim770 Added details.

Comment: What is `_filter`?

Comment: @NitzanTomer Filter is some function that takes in two params viz a predicate and the array/observable that it needs to apply the filter on.

Comment: I think the real question should be "Successful currying strategy in typescript"

Comment: You defined `Curry<T, R>`, but there's no sign of this `R` in the function, why is it there?

Comment: @NitzanTomer That would give me the same error.

Comment: With `Curry<T>`, this: `const filter = Curry(_filter)` seems to be ok

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126216/discussion-between-tushar-and-nitzan-tomer).